Do strawberry seeds have different DNA within the same fruit?
It is my understanding that a strawberry is composed of many small fruits clustered together.
Does that mean each seed within a given strawberry has different DNA? Or are all the seeds in a strawberry clones?

Strawberry seeds will all have different DNA.
It is standard for seeds to have different DNA, even those contained in the same fruit. Normally, the egg cells held in the ovule ultimately come from meiosis, and this process occurs separately in each ovule. Similarly, the sperm cells held within pollen grains were produced from a meiosis event. So, just as human gametes all contain different DNA, even gametes from one person, so do plant gametes.
Your question also touches on the seed/fruit arrangement of strawberries. A strawberry can be termed both an aggregate fruit and an accessory fruit:

An aggregate fruit is where multiple separate ovaries are held together on a single flower. In case of the strawberry, each "seed" on the red flesh developed from an ovary, and a true seed is held within each one. A raspberry is another example of an aggregate fruit, where each fleshy ball developed from a separate ovary.*
An accessory fruit is one where the "fruity" part of the fruit has developed from some tissue that's outside of the ovary. The red flesh of the strawberry has developed from the receptacle, which is the tissue that all the ovaries were attached to. A raspberry is not an accessory fruit because in that case the ovaries themselves have become fruity.

However, none of that seed/fruit arrangement makes any difference to the fertilization processes of the strawberry, which mirrors other seed plants.

*In some strict definitions, each of these developed ovaries could be considered a separate fruit. However, it is also common and useful to apply the term to the unit overall.

The challenge in understanding (flowering/angiosperm) plant reproduction is that there is such a variation in flower types and structures.
Gynoecium ('female part') > pistil(s) > carpel(s) > ovary(ies) > ovule(s)
For any flower with female parts (as some species may be dioecious), it may contain one or more pistils, comprising one or more ovaries that can contain multiple ovules.
The key here is that the ovule is the basic unit of fertilisation. The pollen tube may enter the ovule, allowing for double fertilisation to occur. Of course, as with everything in nature, not all ovules may become successfully fertilised within a given flower. As a rule of thumb, one ovule gives rise to one seed (if successfully fertilised).
The number of ovules per plant varies, e.g. for tomato this is in the region of up to 300-400 ovules (ref1). In the case of an apple, this comprises five carpels, each containing two ovules. So there is a theoretical maximum of 10 seeds per fruit (ref2). And fruits such as apricots (and other drupes from Prunus spp.) contain two ovules, but, confusingly, one of the two regresses, so only one seed is produced (ref3).
From a genetic standpoint, each ovule is an independent site for sexual reproduction. The (female and male) gametes are produced via meiosis (so they are genetically distinct, even if originating from the same individual). Therefore, each ovule will contain slightly different egg cell, fertilised by a slightly different sperm cell, giving rise to genetically different seeds. So each seed within a tomato fruit is different; conceptually they are all siblings (rather than twins/clones).
As a side note, there is a special case of self-fertilisation - where pollen originates from the same plant as the ovule it fertilises. In this case, the genetic diversity is reduced, but the overall principles hold (as each gamete is generated by meiosis).
And coming back to the strawberries, the fruit type (whether is simple,like a tomato, or aggregate, like a strawberry) does not fundamentally change the genetic make-up of the individual seeds (as they are independently generated, even in simple fruits).
